# extract mount points from the atacontrol output in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to extract the mount points `ad0` and `ad4` in following example in bash.

`atacontrol  list
ATA channel 0:
    Master:  ad0 <ST9500530NS/SN04> SATA revision 2.x
    Slave:       no device present
ATA channel 1:
    Master:      no device present
    Slave:       no device present
ATA channel 2:
    Master:  ad4 <UNIGEN FLASH/30/06/03> ATA/ATAPI revision 0
    Slave:       no device present
ATA channel 3:
    Master:      no device present
    Slave:       no device present
ATA channel 4:
    Master:      no device present
    Slave:       no device present`

I am trying to extract the mount points "ad*" into an array which would be further used for other things. This is part of a shell script which would use this array.

Thanks for your help with multiple solutions.

Comment: looping and matching with shell (and sed or grep or...) would be wrong, not traditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` way to do it.
It make sure only `ad` form lines with `Master` or `Slave` are used.

```
arr=($(awk '/(Master|Slave): +ad/ {print $2}' file))
echo ${arr[0]}
ad0
echo ${arr[1]}
ad4
```

Comment: Thanks. This is cleaner and better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `grep -o` and character classes to obtain the mount points:

```
grep -o ad[0-9]* file
```

Output:

```
$ grep -o ad[0-9]* dat/atacntl.txt
ad0
ad4
```

If you want the values in your array:

```
devlist=( $(atacontrol list | grep -o ad[0-9]*) )
```

Comment: Sure, every once in a while I'm actually useful `:p`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/ad[[:digit:]]\+/p' file
```

Comment: the string "ad[followedby}number" is the regex here i am trying to avoid hardcoding ad0/ad4. do you hae any suggestion

Comment: edited @jay-d  Note [[:digit:]]* can be without digits while [[:digit]]\+ must contain at least one digit

Comment: I am putting all the extracted drives to an array.  `devlist=$(atacontrol list | sed -n '/ad[[:digit:]]+/p')  ; echo $devlist` this doesn't show anything in the array

Comment: add \ before +, strange sed notation, corrected in answer @jay-d

Comment: `devlist=$(atacontrol list | sed -n '/ad[[:digit:]]\+/p')  ; echo $devlist `

no output, array is still empty

Comment: yes sorry. i meant to say that i am trying to put  all the ad* into an array . devlist should show atleast the fist element, right ?

Comment: waiting for cleaner awk soluton

Comment: :-) i've skipped awk from learning (for now since i like it also, reading your answers), and directly swimmed in python waters

Comment: Requirement is that I need a bash based array of all the mount points from the atacontrol list output. I don't want to parse individual word from the entire output string and then do some kind of "ad*" comparison. I tried few things with sed but that would replace the stuff and not give me "ad*"s in nice array

Comment: i think we should go to sleep and leave OP to do some google searching

Comment: guys .. there is no python here.. its pure bash /shell scripting

Comment: yes, many posibilites, many languages, problem to be solved. Sometimes bash is mind blowing, so...

Comment: josifoski,  Ed   thanks guys for your help david 's solution works for me.

Comment: @JayD a script that produces the desired output from some sample input is the starting point for a solution, not the end point. THINK about what it's doing - it's finding every string that starts with `ad`. Are you SURE the 2 characters `a` and `d` will never appear side by side anywhere else in your input file (e.g. the word `grade` appears somewhere) and that your mount points will always start with `ad`? Seems like a very unnecessary gamble to me.